# why i am not getting the expected output?

Tags: c, printf

```
int main()
{
  int x;
  float y;
  char c;

  x = -4443;
  y = 24.25;
  c = 'M';

  printf("\nThe value of integer variable x is %f", (float)x);
  printf("\nThe value of float variable y is %d", y);
  printf("\nThe value of character variable c is %f\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The value of integer variable x is -4443.000000
The value of float variable y is 0
The value of character variable c is 24.250000
```

Why am I not getting the expected output?

But when I am using external casting I am getting expected output which is:

```
The value of integer variable x is -4443.000000
The value of float variable y is 24
The value of character variable c is 77.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

> why i am not getting the expected output ?

Short answer: Because your expectations are wrong.

You're instructing the compiler to read an integer from where `y` is. Which is wrong. Format specifier don't tell the compiler to do casts, just what type to expect, and trust *you* to provide the right type.

The behaviour can be due to the fact that, **for example**, a `float` is stored in 8 bytes. The high-order bytes will be `0` in this case. But an `int` is stored in 4 bytes. So you tell the compiler read the `int` from where `y` is, it reads the first 4 bytes, which are `0`, and prints `0`...

EDIT: As John pointed out in the comments, this is UB, which means that anything can happen:

**7.21.6.1/9**

> If a conversion speciﬁcation is invalid, the behavior is undeﬁned.282) If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion speciﬁcation, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Comment: Or can do anything else due to UB.

Comment: @jsn is it UB? I don't know C that well so I didn't know for sure, you should add an answer, you have +1 from me for the reference ;)

Comment: Are you sure about that explanation? `float` is still usually 4 bytes the last time I checked. What appears to be happening is that underlying architecture uses the registers for arguments and stores all floating point in floating point registers and in the integer registers otherwise. The printf implementation attempts to read the corresponding integer register (which happens to be zero) in the second case. The third case attempts to read the corresponding float register and happens to find `24.25` due to the previous call. Still UB I believe.

Comment: `float` is usually stored in 4 bytes, true, but the conversion that happens for functions such as `printf` is to `double`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: it is indeed UB - 7.21.6.1/9: "If a conversion speciﬁcation is invalid, the behavior is undeﬁned.282) **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion speciﬁcation, the behavior is undeﬁned.**"

Comment: I was wandering that, when i was trying to print the character value using a float type format specifier(without using external casting), the result was displaying the value of the previous float type variable... why it is so??

Comment: @RSP undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: While the C standard does not define the behavior, that does not mean that other things in the world do not and that it is not useful to understand what happened.

Comment: @RSP: Likely, the previous float value was display because the previous float value was stored in a floating-point register to be passed as an argument in a previous call, and it remained there during the subsequent call to printf. See my answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: It is not correct to say that an integer conversion specifier in a position that corresponds to a floating-point value instructs the compiler to read from where the floating-point value is. It instructs printf to read from where an integer value should be. The floating-point value might be there, or it might be someplace completely different, depending on how the target platform passes arguments of different types.

Comment: @EricPostpischil that's why I said *for example*. Multiple behaviours are possible, subject to alignment and other platform/compilers specifics.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: The sentence “You're instructing the compiler to read an integer from where y is.” is false.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: true, but we aren't told anything about the underlying platform (compiler, hardware, OS, etc.), so any speculation as to *why* `0` vs. some other output is pretty baseless.  Unless you intend to take advantage of UB for some specific purpose, it's usually not worth getting down into the details of *why* you got a specific result.

Comment: @JohnBode: Understanding computer behavior beyond the C standard is useful: (a) When programming in languages other than C. (b) When debugging programs and the observed behavior gives clues about what is wrong. (c) When designing software to make efficient use of the machine. (d) When designing compilers and language standards, so that they can be designed to work well with machines. (e) Understanding why languages and compilers are the way they are. I am sure there are other situations too, but, clearly, advocating ignorance is unproductive.

Comment: @EricPostpischil no one is doing that. I too would like to know. If you can explain the behaviour from the standpoint of the compiler, with documentation and supporting evidence, add an answer. Until someone does that, undefined behaviour & anything can happen is the closes there is.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I did add an answer, and it does explain the behavior. Computers are not some black box nobody can look into. The behavior asked about is completely understandable and is the consequence of passing floating-point arguments in separate registers from integer arguments.

Comment: @EricPostpischil +1 for the effort then.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Since you asked for documentation, I added a URL to my answer pointing to the ABI documents for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

Many computing platforms pass different types of arguments in different ways. On some platforms, floating-point arguments are passed in special floating-point registers. On most platforms, integer arguments are passed in general processor registers. Large arguments, such as structures, are stored somewhere in memory, and a pointer is passed instead (invisibly to the C source code). Once the few registers available for arguments are used, the remaining arguments are typically passed on the stack.

When you call printf, the compiler does not match the arguments you pass to the conversion specifiers in the format string. (Except that a good compiler will check and issue a warning if the types do not match.) In order to operate, the printf routine reads the format string and, when it finds a conversion specifier, it reads data from where the corresponding argument **should** be. If you specify “%d” but pass a float, the printf routine may read data from a general processor register, but the float value is in a floating-point register. Therefore, the value that is printed will be whatever data happened to be in the general processor register.

Similarly, when you specify “%f” but pass an integer, the printf routine may read from a floating-point register, but the integer value is in a general processor register.

The compiler will **not** convert printf arguments to the target type and **might not** warn you about the mismatches. You must match the conversion specifiers in the format string to the argument types.

Bonus: [Here are documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/000-Introduction/introduction.html) describing how arguments are passed to subroutines on one platform (Mac OS X).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot format a char as a float `"%f"`, use `"%c"` or `"%d"` instead. I find that http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/ is a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

The format specifiers and the types of the arguments don't match, which I believe causes undefined behavior. `printf` doesn't do casting for you, so you have to explicitly cast the arguments.